# .NET library for Box View API

Tags: box-view-api

I am generating word documents on my web server using DocX and I want users to download them as PDF, since there are not many convertors for this task, I was thinking of using Box View API (used to be Crocodoc), since I have a developer account.

I am able to find .NET library for Box API but could not find .NET library for Box View API.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the .NET API for box view:
https://github.com/crocodoc/dot-net-box-view